# ul id is not firing if put in .js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have written a code for implementing jQuery accordion. It is working fine in normal web from but in content place holder JavaScript *(.js file)* not firing the client id for ul tag. Please take a look at the code below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<style>
    body, input {
        font-family: Calibri, Arial;
    }

    #Accordion {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 250px;
    }

        #Accordion li {
            display: block;
            background-color: #323232;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
            list-style: circle;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: white;
        }

        #Accordion ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            display: none;
        }

            #Accordion ul li {
                font-weight: normal;
                cursor: auto;
                color: #323232;
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: 0 0 0 7px;
            }

        #Accordion a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            #Accordion a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
</style>

<script>
    $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > li').click(function () {

        if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > ul').slideUp(300);
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });

    $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > ul:eq(0)').show();

</script>

<div style="float: left; padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;">
                    <ul id="Accordion" class="accordion" runat="server">
                        <li>Sports</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Golf</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cricket</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <li>Technology</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <li>Latest</li>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Obama</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Iran Election</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Health Care</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you would need to put your code into `.ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code goes here
});
```

#### Explanation:

The problem is that when you fired your code, the content has not fully been loaded. It was not on the ***[DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)*** yet and as a result ignored by jQuery. If you run it in you HTML file, most like you'd put your code right under and because it was executed afterwards, that element was found and your code worked expected way!

Read more about [jQuery .ready() function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

#### EDIT 1:

Place your code in *.js* file and wrap it in `.ready()` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > li').click(function () {
        if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > ul').slideUp(300);
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
    $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %> > ul:eq(0)').show();
});
```

#### EDIT 2:

I have doubts about `<%= Accordion.ClientID %>` and whether it will be processed properly from inside of *.js* file just plainly like this?

#### EDIT 3:

Like I said, your ASP script will not process `<%= Accordion.ClientID %>` properly from inside of *.js* file.

I would create a ***var*** and then would get its *value* by using jQuery.

1. Put this somewhere into your *HTML* (ASP page):

`<div id="current_client_id" style="display:none"><%= Accordion.ClientID %></div>`

1. Then in your *jQuery* code, grab that ***var*** and add this to your old code:

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var AccordionClientID = $('#current_client_id').html(); 
      $('#' + AccordionClientID + ' > li').click(function () {
            if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('#' + AccordionClientID + ' > ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        });
        $('#' + AccordionClientID + ' > ul:eq(0)').show();
    });
```

Comment: i used the code provided by you. but still it is not working for me.

Comment: Just updated the last edit 3, code has an typo in it! Try again!

Comment: @llia: $('#selected_members_total').html(), may i know from where this id has been declared

Comment: From that part that I asked you to put on your page: `<div id="current_client_id"><%= Accordion.ClientID %></div>` and then processed in jQuery code: `var AccordionClientID = $('#current_client_id').html();`

Comment: If it doesn't work remove second plus in :  `+ AccordionClientID + '` and leave it as `+ AccordionClientID '`

Comment: Yes, you must also hide it by adding `display:none`, edited again!

Answer (score -1):

Put your code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %>'+' li').click(function () {
            if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %>' +  ' ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        });
        $('#' + '<%= Accordion.ClientID %>'+  ' ul:eq(0)').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I modified the code try it again, and if the code not working with you try to put javascript alert in the start of the function to trace your code.